# error when running procedure mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I found this procedure here in the mantis database and need to run it straight to the bank to see what results it will bring , but do not know how to perform this procedure , which way to understand this ? How do you perform this procedure specifies?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testlink.PR_SEL_RELAT_PRODUTIVIDADE;
CREATE PROCEDURE testlink.`PR_SEL_RELAT_PRODUTIVIDADE`(
   idProjetoTestLink INT,
   idPlanoTeste      INT,
   DataReferencia    VARCHAR(10),
   idProjetoMantis   INT)
BEGIN
      DECLARE vDataReferencia   DATE;
      DECLARE vIdQuery          char(36);

      /* Carrega os dias Testes na tabela Tempor?ria */
      SELECT FN_SELECIONA_CASO_TESTES(idProjetoTestLink, idPlanoTeste)
        INTO vIdQuery;

      SELECT DATE(DataReferencia)
        INTO vDataReferencia;

SELECT a.username,
       a.realname,
       sum(a.falha) falha,
       sum(a.passou) passou,
       SUM(a.bloqueado) bloqueado,
       sum(a.EmExecucao) EmExecucao,
       sum(a.DefeitosFechados) DefeitosFechados,
       sum(a.DefeitosReabertos) DefeitosReabertos
  FROM (SELECT X.LOGIN_TESTER username,
               X.NOME_TESTER realname,
               CASE STATUS WHEN 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Falha,
               CASE STATUS WHEN 'p' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Passou,
               CASE STATUS WHEN 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Bloqueado,
               0 EmExecucao,
               0 DefeitosFechados,
               0 DefeitosReabertos
          FROM testlink.tmp_result_report X
         WHERE X.ID_QUERY = vIdQuery
               AND X.DATA_EXECUCAO = vDataReferencia
        UNION ALL
        SELECT X.LOGIN_TESTER username,
               X.NOME_TESTER realname,
               0 Falha,
               0 Passou,
               0 Bloqueado,
               CASE STATUS WHEN 'r' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END EmExecucao,
               0 DefeitosFechados,
               0 DefeitosReabertos
          FROM testlink.tmp_result_report X
         WHERE X.ID_QUERY = vIdQuery
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user.username,
               user.realname,
               0 Falha,
               0 Passou,
               0 Bloqueado,
               0 EmExecucao,
               CASE WHEN bug.resolution <> 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  DefeitosFechados,
               CASE WHEN bug.resolution = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  DefeitosReabertos
          FROM mantis.mantis_bug_table bug,
               mantis.mantis_category_table categ,
               mantis.mantis_user_table user
         WHERE     bug.project_id = idProjetoMantis
               AND bug.category_id = categ.id
               AND bug.status = 90      -- Fechado
               AND bug.resolution <> 10 -- Aberto
               AND date(FROM_UNIXTIME(bug.last_updated)) = vDataReferencia
               AND bug.reporter_id = user.id) a
  WHERE a.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.username;
END;
```

> **#1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE testlink.PR_SEL_RELAT_PRODUTIVIDADE; expected 4, got 0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute a procedure using `CALL` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html)).
With your procedure, you execute it using:

```
CALL PR_SEL_RELAT_PRODUTIVIDADE([int], [int], [string], [int]);
```

For example:

```
CALL PR_SEL_RELAT_PRODUTIVIDADE(3, 4, 'foo', 5);
```